# Запись видео, голоса, и фото на сайте через браузер

Tags: php

Добрый день. Нужно реализовать на сайте запись видео, голоса, фото - и отправку файла на сервер. Все это с браузера смартфона.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении плыть?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

INPUT + Обработка файла на формат.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```